# Javascript conflicts with Asp.net runat=server attribute

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, runatserver

I am running some java script with a couple html controls. Everything works fine.

Except when I add the runat = " server" attribute to the html control, so I can access it in the code behind, the java script function does not work. Is this a common thing? Is there a work around for using a runat = " server" attribute with java script?

Or how can I access my Html control in the code behind WITHOUT using the run at server attribute?

Confused.

Comment: copy/paste the code in question please

Comment: Hi EB.  You are generalizing your issue.  Instead, you need to be specific and explain exactly which control you are attempting to access via codebehind, or this thread will turn into a game of 20 questions.

Comment: We really need to see your code to help you with this one. That said, my suspicion is that when you add `runat="server"` to the HTML control, the ID of the control is being changed to something like `ctl00_OriginalIdHere` which is causing your javascript to break. What version of asp.net are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely occuring because your markup looks something like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <div runat="server" id="myDiv">
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

i.e. You're using a MasterPage or something else that acts as an [`INamingContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.inamingcontainer.aspx). This results in the ID that's written out in the markup looking something like this:

```
<div>
    <div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_myDiv">
    </div>
</div>
```

If you're using asp.net 4 you can change your markup for `myDiv` by adding `clientidmode="Static"` and you'll then get:

```
<div>
    <div id="myDiv">
    </div>
</div>
```

Meaning your javascript will work again. If you're using earlier versions of asp.net then you'll need to do as SHAKKIR SHABBIR suggested and use `<%=myDiv.ClientId%>` to reference the element in your javascript so you get the "renamed" version of the ID that asp.net produces.

Comment: Rob, this is nice information to me. I had not known of ClientIDMode=Static .... Thanks for the added info!

Comment: Ok. Thank you both Shakir and Rob. I tried both solutions and Rob's worked! I was not aware of this attribute either. Shakir, I'm sure your suggestion works too, I must have done something wrong on my side. Thank you both. One last question, I have an HTML Button submit which calls the javascript function "initialize". Is there any way to call this button click event or javascript function in the page load event? Thanks guys!

Comment: That's an entirely different question, so, ask a new one for it =) And, glad I helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, runat="server" is ok.

You need to modify the javascript.

If your control is input as:

```
<input id="control_ID" runat="server" />
```

Use <% = control_ID.ClientId %> in javascript to reference the control

it will work fine. However, if this doesnt work, share your code. I will solve!

Answer (score 0):

```
<img alt="Calendar" onmouseover="javascript:this.style.cursor='hand';"
                    src="~/images/Calander_0.png" 
                    id="ImgCalender"  
                    onclick ="javascript:showCalendarControl('<%=txtAppointmentDate.ClientID  %>','mm/dd/yyyy');" 
                    runat="server"  />
```

If run at server is set JavaScript does not work